# I have Node Js API, and I need to grant sequential execution on some endpoints

Tags: javascript, node.js, locking

I have Node Js API, and I need to grant sequential execution on some endpoints, for instance, all requests /users/id1 should be sequential, but  /users/id1 &  /users/id2 should not be. What is the best practice to achieve this ?

Comment: I don't really understand your question but you suggest you to look at middleware structure for routing: https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect and http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#using-middleware if you are using express.js

Comment: @iKoala I'm doing some async calls inside my controllers, for instance charging user and setting some status in my database, but if request come two times, because of front issue, or api calls, user gets charged twice, because while finishing 1 payment, second payment comes and status in database is not updated.

Comment: Well, if you want the requests for specific routes to be processed sequentially (for whatever reason, I mean, it totally destroys the purpose of node) then I would recommend implementing a queue.

But I don't really get it either. You don't have to worry about inconsistencies in the database as long as it is ACID compliant. Just don't charge a user twice if the transaction as already been processed. Should be a simple check.

I really don't want to step on anybodies toes, but do you really know what you are doing handling financial data?

Comment: @MarvinH. Thanks for the feedback, well we resolved the problem with https://www.npmjs.com/package/redlock . May be the problem isn't stated clear enough, but the problem is we had resources associated with each payment, and it takes time to complete all actions (async) and we need to use some kind of locking, so that whenever you access same resource twice or more it will be sequential. Here I refer to locking more in abstract, code level, than database level.